# Syntax problem with ODE

Tags: syntax

The problem is I can clearly see that my input is not interpreted correctly. I write

```
eq1 == x'[t] == - y/((x - t)^2 + y^2)
```

and it is interpreted as the following

> ```
> 1 == Derivative[1][x][t] == -(y/((x - t)^2 + y^2))
> ```

I don't know why. My Mathematica version is 11.2.

Comment: An equation uses `Equal ( == ) ` rather than `Set ( = ) `: `eq1 = x'[t] == -y/((x-t)^2+y^2)`

Comment: This is what I typed now:eqa == x'[t] == - y[t] / ((- t + x[t])^2 + y[t]^2)

Comment: The interpretation is :   x'[t] == - y[t] / ((- t + x[t])^2 + y[t]^2)

Comment: As shown in my earlier comment, use `eqa = x'[t] == - y[t] / ((- t + x[t])^2 + y[t]^2)` Your equation is the RHS of your assignment (Set).

Comment: Following your guide, still when I try to use NDSolve, and type:     sol = NDSolve[{eqa,eqb, x[0] == 0, y[0]==1}, {x,y},{t,0,1}] .   Its interpretation skip the eqa and eqb.

Comment: Start with a fresh kernel or clear all variables, then try again. If that doesn't work, edit your question to include all of the code you are using. Put the code in code blocks.

Comment: Don't know how to include code blocks. I am the beginner and I am so frustrated now. I took a snapshot of the code but then found that I am even not allowed to send pics.

Comment: See [`Markdown help`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help). Indent four spaces for a code block.

Comment: What is your second equation with the derivative y'[t] ?